# Unexpected output for a recursive function to compute sum of n numbers

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to write a simple recursive function to compute the sum of `n` numbers. So, I wrote the code below and it works well, but when I tried to print `sum` inside the recursive function, it prints (at the main function) a random number.

```
int SumRec(int n, int sum)
{
    sum+=n;
    if(n==1)
        return sum;
    else
        SumRec(n-1,sum);
    cout<<sum<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<SumRec(2,0)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `SumRec` doesn't always return the promised `int`.  This wreaks havoc on a program. Who knows what will happen.

Comment: you need to pay attention to that compiler warning that states "not all code paths return a value in a non-void function"

Comment: As a note, recursive functions to do this sort of thing are usually really awful. There's only so much stack space.

Comment: Please be careful with the compiler warnings. Not all execution branches of your function return values, and returned values of recursion calls are ignored.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for the advice, I am doing it as an HW and I am trying to figure out, what causes that output.... as it works fine without this line of code " cout<<sum<<endl;" at the end of the recursive function.

Comment: It has undefined behaviour regardless of that line, but it's only with that line present that you observe it. As others have pointed out you're not returning an `int` through every branch of that `if`, only one, and as such it's returning junk for `n!=1`. Turn on all your compiler warnings to catch simple slips like this.

Comment: "Does not crash" is not the same as "works" :)

Comment: @tadman Ok, I will handle this by adding return keyword in the "else" branch like this 
"return SumRec(n-1,sum);" is this ok?

Comment: Not all control paths return a value so add: `return sum;` in SumRec();

Comment: So long as each branch `return`s something then you're going to get rid of the undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user2362790 bingo. Also remove the `cout`. Once both sides of the if statement `return` that `cout` is dead code that cannot be reached.

Comment: @tadman All right, I got it now.... thank you very much for your help,

Comment: A note on Compiler Errors and Warnings. An error means the grammar is incorrect and cannot be parsed, identifiers used were not declared, or any of dozens of reasons the compiler cannot transform the code into a run-able program. Unfortunately there is a huge difference between a run-able program and a program that does what you want.

A compiler warning seems less dire because the compiler can make a program, but a warning means that the code will produce a program that does not necessarily behave as expected. A warning is often the first line of defense against bugs.

Comment: Thanks for all of you, I have really benefited from all of your answers and I really enjoyed asking for the problems that I face and to learn from other experts.

Answer (score 3):

You should ensure that `SumRec` returns an integer values as long as you promised when declaring it. I see that if `n == 1` it returns `sum` but otherwise doesn't! So you should make it look like:

```
int SumRec(int n, int sum){
    sum += n;
    if(n == 1)
        return sum;
    else
        sum = SumRec(n - 1, sum);

    cout << sum << endl;
    // when done from recursion i should return a value as i promised
    return sum;   
}
```